# How can I call a function in controller with parameters from the view?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've got a controller-view. I want to draw out the content of the view with one of my function from the controller.

For example **mycontentview**:

```
<h1>$parameter</h2>;
```

I load this view in **$data** in **MyController**:

```
public function index(){
    $data['parameter'] = "some parameter";
    $body = $this->load->view('mycontentview', $data, true);
    $data = array();
    $data['content'] = $body;

    $this->load->view('templates/header');
    $this->load->view('indexview', $data); 
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');
}

public function new_content($param1){
    $data['parameter'] = $param1;
    $body = $this->load->view('mycontentview', $data, true);
    $data = array();
    $data['content'] = $body;

    $this->load->view('templates/header');
    $this->load->view('indexview', $data); 
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');
}
```

So for the first time I load in the ***indexview***. There I can echo the ***$body*** which contain the content from ***mycontentview*** and on a button click I want to call the ***new_content*** function with a parameter. How can I do it?

Comment: you can use `anchor tag` in your `mycontentview`

Comment: @M.Hemant What do you think exactly?

Comment: you want a way from view to the controller with the parameter. can you show your `mycontentview` view?

Comment: @M.Hemant You can see it, There is a <h1> tag. Thats all. I want to call mycontentview inside another view. mycontentview just a part of the whole view, what I want to generate with a parameter

Answer (score 0):

you can add this to `mycontentview` view

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url('YourController/new_content/'.$parameter); ?>" title="Button Title">Button Text</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this Code in your view file to redirect.

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url('Controller/Method/'.$Parameter); ?>" class="Your Class" id="Your Id">Your Button</a>
```

Or you can also use the anchor() function but before using anchor() function you have to load the [URL helper](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html)

```
$this->load->helper('url');
echo anchor('Controller/Method/'.$Parameter, 'Your Button', array('class'=>'Your Class','id'=>'Your Id'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use get instance method in codeigniter like

```
$ci =& get_instance();
$ci->functionName($something);
```

You can call function in your **current controller** or the function in your **base controler** in HMVC or **CI_Controller** in MVC

I think this will help you, please let me know any problem

Comment: It won't help, because I want to call the function, in the view.